# Lock the orientation for only the main UIViewController - iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, program-entry-point

I would like to know how I could lock the orientation for my main View Controller but allow my users to rotate to landscape for all the View Controllers?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For MainViewController:

```
   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
   }
```

Other ViewControllers

```
   -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
   {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
   }
```

Comment: Your the best! I just had to change UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape for the second one to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
}
```

The default for iPad is

```
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll
```

while the iPhone default is

```
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
```

you shouldn't need to implement anything else on your other view controllers

Answer (score 0):

This may help you..

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
return NO;
}
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```